# Google App Engine: Custom namespace approach validation

Tags: google-app-engine

I wanted to get an opinion on the below approach to namespaces.

Basic thoughts

1. Multiple organizations will access the application on google app engine using the same url.
2. Google authentication used to authenticate users

Approach:

1. Users of all organizations are created in the default namespace.
2. On user login, namespace is set based on the orgname property in the user entity. Namespace value is set in the session.
3. For logged in users, namespace is set in the dispatch method of the BaseHandler. So that the namespace is set at once central location.
4. All org specific entities (except users) are created in the above namespace
5. For user entity appropriate filter is applied in the query

Please comment on the assumptions and approach.

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Vishal

Comment: Kindly help. Best Regards, Vishal